# Difference between Dynamic Binary Instrumentation and Analysis

Tags: testing, valgrind

I am reading about automated bug finding techniques and in ([Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/valgrind2007.pdf)) paper it mentions that Valgrind is a dynamic binary instrumentation framework for building dynamic binary analysis tools. This maybe a bit stupid but I am a bit confused about the naming here. What exactly is the difference between instrumentation and analysis ? (I know that they are different words but what is the difference in practice ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instrumentation is collecting data. Analysis is, well, analyzing it. The reason why Valgrind mentions "dynamic" is because there are also static analysis tools that actually analyze the code without running a program whereas Valgrind analyzes a binary code while running a binary.

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis

Answer (score 0):

The implementation details of this automated bug-finding [tool](https://pingcap.com/blog/squashed-bugs-served-hot-and-fresh-with-failure-rate-heatmaps/) should answer your question:

- You use dynamic binary instrumentation tools to instrument the source code for further analysis.
- You use different algorithms or techniques to analyze the code, such as statistical debugging introduced in the article.